# iterating through instance of HashSet class, expect random order but the results are always the same order

Tags: java, collections, iteration, hashset

I'm trying to learn the concept of Set interface and HashSet class in java. I have read

> when using HashSet class, that there is no guarantee of the sequence
>   of elements when I iterate over.

I have came up with some code and run ten times and it always iterate in the order of insertion. So is this due to luck?

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
set1.add(1);
set1.add(2);
set1.add(3);
set1.add(2);

Iterator i1 = set1.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(i1.next());
}
```

Comment: yes it's just a coincidence, `HashSet` is unordered and unsorted. if you want order of elements to be maintained , you can use `LinkedHashSet`

Comment: Integer's hashcode implementation uses that number (might as well). so if the entries are stored by hashcode you'll see the numbers in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES. It's due to "luck". It depends on the JRE implementation! I learned this the *hard way* many years ago when started implementing in Java, and the code was tested on **different platforms**.

If i recall, in windows a **HashSet** iteration was perfectly ordered, but in Mac OSX totally scrambled!

**Bottom line**: Always rely on the docs, and not on the apparent results!

Answer (score 2):

As per the javadoc:

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over time. [...] The iterators returned
>   by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified
>   at any time after the iterator is created

From `Java4` we have `LinkedHashSet` which guarantees that the iteration order and the insertion order is same.